lost decimals when json deserialization use Gson
public class GsonTest {
    class A {
        Float v;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String aStr = "{ v:2752293.58 }";

        A a = gson.fromJson(aStr, A.class);
        System.out.println(a.v);

    }
}

the result will be:
2752293.5
not the expected value: 2752293.58
anyone have the same problem?

if change the field type to BigDecimal, the result will be correct

This question is similar to: Float and double datatype in Java. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

when i change the type to Double,the result is as expected. may be you are right,thanks

JSON doesn't specify floating point behavior.  If it matters to you use a string or fixed point integer (besides that you maybe be hitting a type issue with how you store the data).

The fundamental problem is not anything to do with JSON or Gson.  Rather it is your use of Float (or float).
The Float and float types simply cannot represent 2752293.58 with full precision.  For example,
public class FloatTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Float v = 2752293.58F;
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}

This outputs
2752293.5

In this case, you could use either Double (or double) or BigDecimal.  But note that all of these types have limits on the precision of the numbers that they can represent.
This Q&A explains the difference between the two most commonly used floating point types ... which correspond to Java's float and double types.

I was going to say the same. Upvoted.

as same as joe said above, you both give the same answer. thanks a lot
